# How do you run Spyder without any startup scripts?

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to Python, and for my current work, I don't want Spyder to run any predefined startup scripts. By default, Spyder runs a script called `scientific_startup.py`.

How do I configure Spyder to stop running this file on startup?

Answer (score 4):

To not use `scientific_startup` you need to go to

`Tools > Preferences > Console > PYTHONSTARTUP replacement`

and select the option called

`Default PYTHONSTARTUP script`

*Note*: If that option is active by default, it means you're using a very old Spyder version. I'd recommend you to update it to its latest version (2.3.7).